# Android EditText with image

Tags: android, android-edittext, text-editor

I need to implement `EditText` with multiple line and can add thumbnail of the image or the video and can retrieve meta from URL. But this is not possible in `EditText` so what is another way to complete mentioned objective. I, in simple way, need to create editor.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for smth like [this](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1696) or maybe other WYSIWYG Editor lib.

There is no solution out of the box in android SDK.

Comment: Yes sort of but I need idea to build

Comment: @SayamAbbas this stuff is open source so you could get it and find some ideas there :)